# How to query bitcoin database created by Toshi?

Tags: database, toshi

I want to query Toshi's(https://github.com/coinbase/toshi) database but can't figure it out how to connect to it. It seems like it runs inside a docker container.
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? https://toshi.io/docs/ Have you tried opening `http://<docker container IP>/api/v0/blocks`?

Comment: @NickODell yeah, the node works fine you can try it http://ec2-52-16-210-167.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5000 or api here http://ec2-52-16-210-167.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/api/v0/blocks

Comment: I just want to know how to access PSQL with all the data. I've asked on toshi's github https://github.com/coinbase/toshi/issues/198 two days ago but no answer yet

Comment: I basically don't see the database When I log as postgres `sudo -i -u postgres` user I see only default DBs postrgres, template0, template1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
docker exec -it toshi_db_1 psql -U postgres -d toshi_development
```

Got the answer on a github issue https://github.com/coinbase/toshi/issues/198